# How to (de)serialize correctly to a byte-array using a ObjectOutputStream & ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, arrays, stream, byte

I am aware that an ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream uses headers and this is not really a proper use-case. But anyway I **need** to wrap some data into it using the interfaces DataInput and DataOutput.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        byte[] array = serialize("test");
        String deserialized = deserialize(array);

        System.out.println(deserialized);
    }

    private static byte[] serialize(String test) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

            objectOutputStream.writeUTF(test);

            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }

    private static String deserialize(byte[] array) {
        String temp = null;

        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(array));

            temp = objectInputStream.readUTF();

            objectInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

I don't really get how to get that working. Am I right, that the problem are those headers currently?

Comment: What is not working? You have exception or wrong result? Also can you provide [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post.

Comment: You should post your code in your question because external resources is not reliable, Someone in future may have same problem but will unable to understand your question because of broken link. This time I did it for you, but please do it yourself in future.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `objectOutputStream.flush();` before closing `byteArrayOutputStream`.

`ObjectOutputStream` have its internal buffer so you got only beginning of string in your byte array.

Comment: You should flush `objectOutputStream`  not `byteArrayOutputStream`. Flushing `byteArrayOutputStream` is useless. It always write directly to buffer.

Comment: @Tobseb , in your code you should be doing `objectOutputStream.writeUTF(test);
   objectOutputStream.flush();
   byteArrayOutputStream.close();`